# Any idea on how Lagrange came up with similar functions concept in (proto)group theory?

Tags: mathematics, group-theory, euler

Lagrange defines "similar functions" as functions of the roots of an equation where they change values only at the same kind of permutations of the roots.
What's a possible predecessor of the idea of similar functions?
Euler seems to have used some sort of a function permutation concept in his attempt to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra.